# NodeJS: Run python script in conda environment

Tags: python, node.js, bash, anaconda, conda

I have a lots of python scripts and each has own dependency.
And I create conda environment to each python script and install dependency too.

And I tried many ways like below

#### Tried 1

```js
const childProcess = require('child_process');

const pythonScript = 'test.py';
const environmentName = 'test';

const command = [
  `conda activate ${environmentName}`,
  `python ${pythonScript}`
]
  .map(v => `(${v})`)
  .join(' && ');

const pythonProcess = childProcess.spwan(command, { shell: true });

pythonProcess.stdin.on('data', (data) => console.log(data.toString()));
pythonProcess.stderr.on('data', (data) => console.error(data.toString()));

pythonProcess.on('close', (code) => {
  console.log('Process Exited:', code);
});
```

#### Tried 2

```js
const command = [
  `conda activate ${environmentName}`,
  `python ${pythonScript}`
]
  .map(v => `(${v})`)
  .join(' && ');

const pythonProcess = childProcess.spwan(`bash -lc "${command}"`, { shell: true });
```

#### Tried 3

```js
const command = [
  `source /opt/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh`,
  `conda activate ${environmentName}`,
  `python ${pythonScript}`
]
  .map(v => `(${v})`)
  .join(' && ');

const pythonProcess = childProcess.spwan(`bash -lc "${command}"`, { shell: true });
```

But, in python script, conda environment doesn't enabled (just enabled default conda environemnt).

How can I run python script in specific conda environment in nodejs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `conda activate` command is a shell function, not a true CLI, so it's not available without first launching a shell in interactive mode (assuming you have previously run `conda init`). Try using `conda run` instead. In your first example, I think it would be something like

```javascript
const command = `conda run -n ${environmentName} python ${pythonScript}`
```

This enables one to execute commands in an environment without having to manually activate the environment.

Comment: very thank you! I didn't know that command.  

Can I one more question?

The python script that I will run takes very long time.  
So, I need to receive stdout of python without buffering.  

So I use `python -u` for no buffering python io.
But, it doesn't work in `conda run` command.

Can I use `conda run` without buffering?  
Also, where can I find a reference document about `conda run`? I couldn't find it.

Comment: @TaeSangCho what version of Conda? There is new behavior in Conda v4.8.1 (see [Release Notes](https://github.com/conda/conda/releases/tag/4.8.1)) that was supposed to improve the `conda run` I/O. I think anything before that version just buffers the output until it is complete.

Comment: I'm using conda 4.8.1 (from `conda --version`).  
And I tried `conda run python -u test.py` and `conda run python test.py`.  
But, both commands don't print stdout immediately.

test.py: `import time; for i in range(1, 100): time.sleep(1); print(i);`

Comment: @TaeSangCho in that case, you should post an issue on the Conda repo. Either mention it [in the thread where it was supposedly fixed](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8386) or [create a new Bug Report](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/new?template=Bug_report.md) with your test case. Sorry, I can't really help much beyond that.

Comment: thank you for your help. it's very helpful for me. I will wait for fixing this issue. until then, I will use `/path/to/conda/python -u test.py` and set some environment variables manually.